# If I broke a promise that I made to Bhagwan - specifying the consequence of me breaking it, what can be done?

Tags: karma, sin, naraka, prayaschitta, brahmacharya

I made a promise to Bhagwan that I would not effuse semen for a month, and if I did, I asked Him to throw me in naraka or make me go through animal reincarnation (8.4 million times). I broke it.

Also, I had my upanayana at age 13 but broke the vow because I did not know about the vow and then when I did become aware, I continued to break it because I felt it had already been broken and I was already addicted. I made the vow above on the question such that I thought it could break my addiction but it did not.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! God isn’t actually gonna put you through naraka. He/she is kripalu. Don’t make frivolous statements of naraka etc.  Instead of having an exchange offer with him/her like that you can pray to give you strength to help you keep your vow. Who knows when kripalu will listen? :) unfortunately this being a personal advice may land up being closed on the site. But we hope to see you becoming an active part of the community. When you get enough reputation you can join the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) where these questions can be discussed generally.

Comment: Well there is not anything wrong with self love. Such a promise is therefore useless.